# How to automate an Amazon EC2 instance startup, execution of some commands and shutdown?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I need to download 100 GB of files (it’s in about 150 files) within a 7 day period before they expire.  The download is rate-limited by the host so it takes MUCH longer than the theoretical transfer rate based on normal Internet speeds.  I have a script of curl http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html commands - one line per file.

I had the idea of automatically spinning up n EC2 instances, executing the command and FTPing the files to a central location, then shutting down the machines. How would I do this?

I don't care whether it's Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using one of Canonical's AMIs in conjuction with cloud-init

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

Look for the section about "User-Data Scripts" where you can use the --user-data-file to auto-launch a script on startup. Thus, you can just put all the commands you want to run in the script and put "shutdown -h now" at the end of the script.

Comment: It looks like the official Amazon Linux AMI also supports CloudInit: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/09/introducing-amazon-linux-ami.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) to script such things before.  Easiest to spin up linux images then ssh into them to have them do work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the best solution. But if you are doing this on a regular basis and need something to automatically start and stop your machines, then you may want to look at this product: http://LabSlice.com (with the disclaimer that I am the CTO).

Comment: your product looks great and your site looks terrific too.  I accepted the other answer though because it was more specific about the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

[Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) with the [AWS provider](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) does that easily, and is multi-platform.

Once the `Vagrantfile` is created, then you launch the instance with `vagrant up`, login to it with `vagrant ssh`, and destroy it with `vagrant destroy`. Super-easy.